# Got codec error in VSCode with Python while using windows PowerShell commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, shell, visual-studio-code

I'm new here, but I'm trying to ru some basic windows shell commands from python, but I got some error
in VSCode.

I've got this error in VS Code `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 29: invalid start byte` for this line:    `commandOutput = subprocess.run(["netsh","wlan","show","profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()`

```
import subprocess
import re
import os


if os.name == 'nt':
    print("\n\n\t==== WI-FI ====\n\n\n");       
        
    commandOutput = subprocess.run(["netsh","wlan","show","profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
    #print(commandOutput)
    names = (re.findall("All User Profile     : (.*)\r", commandOutput))
    #print(names)
    wifilist = list()
    if len(names) != 0:
        for name in names:
            wifiProfile = dict()
            profileInfo = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode() # SSID
            if re.search("Security key           : Absent",profileInfo):
                continue
            else:
                wifiProfile["ssid"] = name
                wifiProfilePassword = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()    
                password = re.search("Key Content            : (.*)\r",wifiProfilePassword)
                if password == None: 
                    wifiProfile["password"] = None
                else:
                    wifiProfile["password"] = password[1] 
                wifilist.append(wifiProfile)
                        
    for x in range(len(wifilist)):
        print(wifilist[x])
            
    commandOutput = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network", "mode=Bssid"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
    currentAvailableNetworksNames    = (re.findall("SSID \d : (.*)\r", commandOutput))
    #currentAvailableNetworksBSSID = (re.findall("         Signal             : (\d+)%\r", commandOutput))
    #currentAvailableNetworksStrength = (re.findall("         Signal             : (\d+)%\r", commandOutput))
    #print(currentAvailableNetworksNames);          
    for x in range(len(currentAvailableNetworksNames)):
        print(currentAvailableNetworksNames[x])

    for x in range(len(wifilist)):
        if wifilist[x]["ssid"] in currentAvailableNetworksNames: 
            print(wifilist[x])
else:
    print("NOT SUPPORTED");`
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this code in a system terminal outside of VS Code? and does it run successfully when using the "cmd" terminal?

Comment: That's usually the result of copy-pasting from something that isn't a code editor (like a web site). Type out the line that fails to get parsed by hand. Make sure that it contains strictly ASCII character.